# Fetch Grand total is not working in backend

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to display **Grand total** in custom page in backend.

i can able to display **Subtotal** successfully. but when  i tried to display

**sub total + Shipping charge** [ means Grand total ]. Its not fetching Grand total.

Order view page :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoqA3.png]

```
$tot_price = $item->getBasePrice() * $_qty;

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("increment_id");
$shippingCostIncludingTax = $order->getShippingInclTax();

$main_price = $tot_price + $shippingBaseCostIncludingTax ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use?

```
$order->getGrandTotal();
```

EDIT:

Probably you didn't load the order in the right way by it's id. Use one of below lines.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('10000001'); //use a real increment order id here
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(24999); //use an entity id here
```

After that it's just

```
$order->getGrandTotal();
```

Comment: i tried like `$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("increment_id"); $main_price = $order->getGrandTotal();` , but it gave me 0 as result..... i am sure i did wrong, can you please tell exact code......

Comment: i tried your updated answer, now its displaying `grand total` of order id `10000001` , not the grand total of `current order id`.....

Comment: as the grand total will be different for each orders, i need dynamic solution......

Comment: You have to ofcourse replace the value with your own order id.

Comment: Is it working now? Don't forget to accept answer if the solution is working. If not let me know so I can elaborate.

Comment: yes, as you suggested i replaced with real `order id : 100001906` , so it displayed proper grand total value for that order in custom page, if i check the other order's  customer page, than also its displaying same `grand total`..... but in that order page, i want to display that order id's `grand total`......

Comment: example : order id : `100001906` = > grand total = > 500 = > so in custom page, its displaying 500 thats fine. but for order id : `100001907` = > grand total = > 550 = > but in custom page, its displaying 500 , here i want to display 550 only.....

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, you need a dynamic solution. Insert the id dynamically.

Comment: please tell me what code i need to use for that.....

Comment: Use the order ID which is comming from the URL param. And insert it in the line for getting the model. That should be it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64238/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-akif).